# When NOT to use form-group in Twitter Bootstrap 3?

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap, templates, template-engine

I'm developing a PHP [templating engine](https://github.com/alexweissman/bootsole/tree/htmlbuilder) that will have custom modules designed around Bootstrap 3.

I'm working on a `FormBuilder` module, which will contain `FormField` elements.  These `FormField` elements will automatically render and style each field in the form.

The question is, should I have these `FormField` elements automatically wrap themselves in `<div class='form-group'>` tags?  Is there ever a reason why someone shouldn't use a `form-group` for form components?

If it helps, I plan to have a separate `FormButton` class, since buttons behave/style differently from other form elements.

Edit: After thinking about it a little more, I could use abstract classes to do something like this:

```
class FormBuilder {
    protected $components = [];    // Array of FormComponents
    ...
}

abstract class FormComponent {
    ...
}

class FormGroup extends FormComponent {
    protected $field;    // A FormField object
    ...
}

class FormField extends FormComponent {
    ...
}

class FormButton extends FormComponent {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

It depends on if you intend to have a FormField that handles a group of radio or checkboxes. That is really the only controls that have multiple input tags without a group. You might be best off to include it as optional for both scenarios since never outputting form-group divs or always outputting them will run you into trouble in terms of the look and feel.

Comment: I did notice that on Bootstrap's website, they always seem to use radio/checkbox groups without a `form-group`.  But looking at other projects, especially [formvalidation](http://formvalidation.io/getting-started/#horizontal-form-programmatic-tab), it seems like they wrap groups of checkboxes in `form-group` without any problem.

Comment: Well it depends on how you want it to look in the end. That's why I recommend making the div optional in terms of wrapping the control object in it. That way you get what you want in the situation you want. Flexibility where it makes sense.